# i want to make an app that wright and send pdf to my email

Tags: python, django

I want to make a form that clients can entre they info
and I will receive the information in my email in pdf format  .

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [smtplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html)

This [tutorial](https://www.codespeedy.com/send-email-with-file-attachment-in-python-with-smtp/) can be useful